# How to translate this SQL query into Hibernate's HQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Having used Hibernate before but never to this extent, I have struggled while trying to translate the following query into a valid Hibernate SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM scripts WHERE (script.type LIKE 'DATA'))
AS A JOIN
(SELECT * FROM req_executions  
WHERE (req_executions.fk_database NOT IN 
(SELECT executions.fk_database FROM executions
WHERE executions.fk_script = req_executions.fk_script))
OR ((req_executions.fk_database = 12 AND req_executions.fk_database != 8) 
AND req_execution.fk_database NOT IN (SELECT executions.fk_database FROM execution
WHERE executions.fk_script = req_executions.fk_script)))
AS B
ON (A.id = B.fk_script)
```

The result of this query is a filtered table of scripts that are pending for execution.
I have tried things like:

```
"SELECT req FROM (SELECT s FROM Script s  
WHERE( s.filename LIKE :filename AND s.type = :scriptType AND s.ticketNumber LIKE :ticketNumber ) 
JOIN (SELECT re FROM RequiredExecution re 
WHERE (re.key.databaseId NOT IN (SELECT e.database FROM Execution e WHERE e.script.id = re.key.scriptId))
OR ((re.key.databaseId = :forAllId AND :dbId != :syncId)
AND re.key.databaseId NOT IN
(SELECT e.database FROM Execution e WHERE e.script.id = re.key.scriptId)))) WHERE (s.id = re.key.scriptId)"
```

and using "AS"
but I am still far from a solution. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was forced to use a nativeQuery instead, because "...HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses." as stated in [14.13. Subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries).

Answer (score 0):

I thought you had to select FROM an entity and not from another SELECT ... I don't know if it is possible, seems tough anyway.

You might consider sticking with native SQL query calling `session.createSQLQuery("the native SQL")`.
and `.addEntity(YourEntityClass.class)` to auto map results
and `.setParameter(`, 0 based numbered, while the query uses `?` placeholders instead of :named_parameter.